# How can I find size of any file from SD_Card?

Tags: android, file

I have a `mp 3` file in SD card , I have path of that mp 3 / "any extension"  file.

Now ,

**How can I get the size of the mp 3 file using code ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
        File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "lala.mp3");

        if(file.exists()){

            double bytes = file.length();
            double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
            double megabytes = (kilobytes / 1024);
            double gigabytes = (megabytes / 1024);
            double terabytes = (gigabytes / 1024);
            double petabytes = (terabytes / 1024);
            double exabytes = (petabytes / 1024);
            double zettabytes = (exabytes / 1024);
            double yottabytes = (zettabytes / 1024);

            System.out.println("bytes : " + bytes);
            System.out.println("kilobytes : " + kilobytes);
            System.out.println("megabytes : " + megabytes);
            System.out.println("gigabytes : " + gigabytes);
            System.out.println("terabytes : " + terabytes);
            System.out.println("petabytes : " + petabytes);
            System.out.println("exabytes : " + exabytes);
            System.out.println("zettabytes : " + zettabytes);
            System.out.println("yottabytes : " + yottabytes);
        }else{
             System.out.println("File does not exists!");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
File filenew = new File(selectedPath);
int file_size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(filenew.length()/1024));
```

and also check out the example

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-file-size-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
File file = new File(PATH OF YOUR FILE);
long fileSize = file.length();
```

After this you can perform whatever action you want on size, means these data you will get in Bytes. You can convert it in KB, MB, GB and so on.